# What is the time complexity of java.util.Collections.sort() method?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, time-complexity

I have written the following class:

```
public class SortingObjectsWithAngleField implements Comparator<Point> {  
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2) {
        double delta = p1.getAngle() - p2.getAngle();
        if(delta == 0.00001)
            return 0;
        return (delta > 0.00001) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Then, in my `main()` method, I have created a `List` to which I add some objects which has "X" and "angle" field.

I then use:

```
Collections.sort(list, new SortingObjectsWithAngleField());
```

What is the complexity of this sort method?

Comment: It’s not relevant to the actual question about the time complexity, but it should be noted that your example `Comparator` implementation is horribly broken. It seems to try to violate *every* rule about comparators, e.g. comparing an object with itself leads to a non-zero result, there is no symmetry and no transitivity. It doesn’t even try to fulfill the main purpose of a comparator, to impose a *total ordering*.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could have read up the docs on Collections sort, but here it is for you:

> The sorting algorithm is a modified
>   mergesort (in which the merge is
>   omitted if the highest element in the
>   low sublist is less than the lowest
>   element in the high sublist). This
>   algorithm offers guaranteed n log(n)
>   performance.

Your Comparator doesn't change this complexity, unless you do anything with loops over your collection in it, which you don't.

Comment: you mean that each sorting method can not have time complexity less than nlogn !! like this sort method , is it right?

Comment: Well depends, if you do some fancy stuff in your comparator which takes more time with the amount of elements in your collection then you will end up with more than n*log(n). But I currently fail to find an example about when you would do that. So in general yes, you get n*log(n) with collections.sort in any case.

Comment: An example is the sort of lists, according to their minimal element. In that case, your comparator will have to traverse all the list to find the minimal element. then your complexity will become m*n*log(n) where m is the average size of your lists.

Comment: Current versions use TimSort which has a time complexity between `O(n)` and `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 8):

You should have found it in the API: [n log(n)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).

Comment: Can this link be updated for java 11 please?

Comment: @cs95 No, because the Javadoc for this method in Java 11 does not mention a guaranteed performance, interestingly.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from Collections.sort -

> The sorting algorithm is a modified
>   mergesort (in which the merge is
>   omitted if the highest element in the
>   low sublist is less than the lowest
>   element in the high sublist). This
>   algorithm offers guaranteed n*log(n)
>   performance

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has stated the [API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)), adding some more relevant information which I found.

If you provide custom comparator, then a modified version of mergesort (also known as `timsort`) is used. The implementation has been borrowed from [list sort for python](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt).

In the best case as few as n-1 comparisons are needed, so `best case is O(n)` and `guaranteed performance in all the cases is O(n.lg(n))`